# Failing a PPA build

Tags: ppa

I'm getting the following build failure when I push to my PPA:

```
dpkg-buildpackage
-----------------

dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package python3-random-quote
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 0.0.2
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution bionic
 dpkg-source --before-build python3-random-quote-0.0.2
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
 debian/rules build
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
 dpkg-genbuildinfo --build=binary
dpkg-genbuildinfo: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; .buildinfo is meaningless
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genbuildinfo --build=binary subprocess returned exit status 25
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build finished at 20190805-2132

Finished
--------

E: Build failure (dpkg-buildpackage died)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here is my control file:

```
Source: python3-random-quote
Maintainer: Thomas Stringer <github@trstringer.com>
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.6

Package: python3-random-quote
Architecture: all
Description: Get a random quote with Python.
Depends: python3-requests
```

This is an exercise to figure out how to build and publish a Python package in a launchpad PPA. Not sure what it wants me to do though with the "no binary artifacts found" issue.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I failed to create a correct debian/rules file.

Comment: What's your rules file ?